# WPF: How can I programatically close a PrintDialog?

Tags: wpf, winapi, printing, printdialog

How can I programatically close a WPF `PrintDialog`? I tried to call `Finalize` on it trough reflection, and that does not close it either. Here is what I tried with:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication15
{
    partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        PrintDialog _printDialog;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            new Thread(OpenDialog).Start();
            new Thread(CloseDialog).Start();
        }

        void OpenDialog()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)OpenDialogImpl);
        }

        void OpenDialogImpl()
        {
            _printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            _printDialog.ShowDialog();
        }

        void CloseDialog()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)CloseDialogImpl);
        }

        void CloseDialogImpl()
        {
            var type = typeof(PrintDialog);
            var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            var finalize = type.GetMethod("Finalize", flags);
            finalize.Invoke(_printDialog, null);
            MessageBox.Show("Finalized");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason the user can't close this dialog manually? Maybe you could post a little background information to your problem, that might help. Thanks!

Comment: I want to implement auto logout.

Comment: I had a similar problem and posted answer in here;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282082/wpf-accessing-opened-print-dialog-and-close-them

Answer (score 0):

Internally, the `PrintDialog` class uses a `Win32PrintDialog` as a local variable to the `ShowDialog()` method, which in turn ends up uses the windows common dialog. Using reflection to get at something to close it might be futile, or at least maddening.

Just a stretch, as I haven't used it, but it might be possible to use [White](http://www.codeplex.com/white) to issue a button press to the dialog's Cancel button. UISpy (mentioned on the White page) might be handy towards that end, too.